# Meu Google Analytics não funciona

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api

Tenho um site no ar e queria ter as informações de quantas pessoas tem acessado por dia e semana, por isso criei um login no google analytics e cadastrei meu site.

O Google Analytics gerou um código com o meu ID pra colocar no head do meu site, eu coloquei, mas fui verificar e aparece que não tem nenhum login no meu site.

Esse é o codigo:

```
<!-- Global Site Tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_TRACKING_ID"></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'UA-114428382-1');
    </script>
```

Coloquei ele na página principal do meu site.

Mas quando vou verificar, os gráficos do google ficam assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem quanto tempo (dias) que vc colocou esse código no site? O Google costuma precisar de um tempo antes de começar a rastrear os dados

Comment: Experimente colocar no fim da página, antes de fechar o `body`, junto com os demais scripts. É somente assim que funciona comigo. Se der certo, busco fontes para uma resposta mais completa.

Comment: Outro detalhe, em sua primeira tag script, onde está `GA_TRACKING_ID` deve estar seu ID, no caso, `UA-114428382-1`

Answer (score 1):

Podem ser inúmeros fatores que fazem os dados não chegarem, por exemplo não informar o id correto na declaração da tag script da API do googleTagManager, como vejo que é o caso do código que colocou aqui:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_TRACKING_ID"></script>
```

Porém vou ignorar isso e assumir que esse é só um exemplo e que você escondeu os códigos por questões de segurança.

Pude notar que você está fazendo o push de informações incorretamente, tente esse formato:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

[...]

window.dataLayer.push({
    'info1' : 'xxxx',
    'info2' : 'xxxx'
});
```

Além disso recomendo que você use uma ferramenta para analise do push de dados como o [dataSlayer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dataslayer/ikbablmmjldhamhcldjjigniffkkjgpo)
Essas ferramentas vão te ajudar a capturar as informações do push mesmo que seu cadastro ainda esteja em fase de aprovação do google (assim como dito pelo [hugocsl](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/97477/hugocsl) nos comentários), garantindo que você veja esses dados mesmo que você ainda não consiga passa-los para o GTM.